# How to loop through a Collection and do operations - Mongodb, Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Mongo Collection with a few thoundsand entries and want to run an .findOneAndUpdate() on each entry. Is there an Mongo operation or so to loop through a hole collection?
In my application I'm calling an API and get approx. 4000 responses. What I want to do now is to check if I allready got the responses in my DB and add the new Data from the response to my existing data.

Currently I do an

```js
response.forEach((entry) => { 
   model.findOneAndUpdate( ... )
}
```

The .findOneAndUpdate() command works for one but not im my loop. And I don't think thats a good solution to loop through everything in my Node Application.

Comment: It don't works in your loop because you need to use await in front of model.find.....

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But I don't now if it is the right approach to do the loop in my Node App or if I better should use Mongo Operations for that. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Yes,it is not good to iterate over 4000 responses, but I can't understand your use case properly.

Comment: My Usecase is that I have users, the users have stats that change over time and I want to keep track on them. So each user has a Data array with all their stats and I want to update them once a week. In the update I add a new field to the Data array. And to set the data to the right person I have to loop over them and check if the IDs Match.

Comment: Ok, so you need to this once a week.
Best way to do is to run a scheduler and pass a function in this what you can do is use mongodb skip and limit parametres

Comment: And update the users in a particular group or limit e.g first do operation on first 1000 users then on next 1000 and so on

Comment: This will help you by not making so much of iterations at same time thereby decreasing sever load.

Comment: allright, I'll search the web for more information but thanks a lot so far!

Comment: Try implementing all this and if not works, we can look together further,just drop a comment here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to make my function asyncronous.

```js
response.forEach(async (entry) => { 
   await model.findOneAndUpdate( ... )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Promise*

```
const promiseArray = response.map((entry) => model.findOneAndUpdate( ... ))

Promise.all(promiseArray).then(....)
```

or you can *await* Promise.all and then continue your work